# Converting ByteBuffer To String remove linebreaks of string which are located at the end of String?

Tags: java, android-studio

I write the following code in the android studio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String hello = "Hello\n\n";
        ByteBuffer buffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(hello.getBytes().length);
        buffer2.put(hello.getBytes());
        buffer2.flip();
        while (true) {
            Log.d(TAG, new String(buffer2.array()));
        }
    }
}
```

It should print Hello with line breaks but as shown in the following screenshot it doesn't.[image]

Comment: You are comparing two different views. I don't remember how logcat handles the `\n` but maybe it just doesn't show it(?)

Comment: As I said it is two diffrent projects which is why it has two logcats and logcat can show linebreak.

Comment: The first picture shows output from a unit test. It's not logcat.

Comment: Right.I will correct it.

Comment: Logcat just doesn't show multiple line breaks. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Converting ByteBuffer To String remove linebreaks of string which are
> located at the end of String?

Answer: No

---

**Demo:**

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "Hello\n\n";
        ByteBuffer buffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(hello.getBytes().length);
        buffer2.put(hello.getBytes());
        buffer2.flip();

        System.out.println(new String(buffer2.array()) + "Hi");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello

Hi
```

Comment: Please test it on android studio and I think there is one line break

Comment: Also I did not make the image by hand it is screenshot taken from android studio

Comment: Did you test it in some other IDE? It may be a problem with the IDE you are using. But you should not worry because the application will behave correctly.